# Multiple Bank statement

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, nigerian-citizens

While applying for a UK Visa in Nigeria with my wife and kid, can we submit 4 bank statements? One of the statements is our joint business account, the second is my salary account from my part-time job, the 3rd statement is my personal and other contract job and the 4th is my wife's personal account. I hope it's okay if I submit them all since we receive money from all of them.

Comment: @MadHatter I don't think so, it doesn't say anything about multiple statements

Comment: @Daniil I disagree - the linked answer is detailed as to the *why* of providing bank statements - if multiple statements provide the right level of evidence, they are acceptable.  The linked answer gives the *why*, and that answers this question as well.

Answer (score 0):

> One of the statements is our joint business account, the second is my salary account from my part-time job, the 3rd statement is my personal and other contract job and the 4th is my wife's personal account.

This is a good selection of bank statements (in my opinion).

It shows:

- How you are earning the money
- You are earning the money lawfully
- You have jobs to support your income and have a stable source of income
- You and your wife have money/savings to be able to finance your trip and will not have to work illegally to get money

The more of those you prove, the higher your chances of getting a visa.

In the [list of supporting documents issued by the UK Government](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk) it doesn't say anything about not being allowed to provide bank statements, it even uses plural form indicating you can submit more than one:

> - bank statement**s**

But note:

> - bank statements or letters issued more than 1 year before the date of application

---

> I hope it's okay if I submit them all since we receive money from all of them.

Since it's allowed and helps you with getting a visa, why not?