# Importance of Tax certificate in UK Visa visit visa application in Nigeria

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, applications

My friend want to apply for UK visit visa. But he doesn't have certificate. Could it affect his visa application

Answer (score 7):

**This seems like a scam**

While a Nigerian citizen will need a Visa to visit the UK, a tax certificate isn't listed on the [Documents you must provide](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/documents-you-must-provide) nor the [full list of supporting documents you can provide](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk).

While the question is very short, this looks like it could be the case of a common scam where a "friend" you met online wants to visit you / fell in love with you / is going to give you several millions, yet argues to need to pay for some supporting documents (or even bribe their officials) before exiting the country, thus slowly getting money for the victim with different excuses.

Comment: All of the OP’s other questions have been about applying for a UK visa from Nigeria, so this may not be a scam. One of the questions refers to a business https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157741/multiple-bank-statement in which case providing a tax certificate would be helpful to show that earnings stated in the visa application and bank account transactions are legitimate.

Comment: It is also a good way of proving actual earnings - people rarely report and pay tax on money a business did not make.